# Pass PK into model form (not logged in user)

Tags: django, django-forms

I would like to use a model form on the django.auth user, but I want to be able to pass in the PK to the model to manage other users, not the logged in user.

Is there a way to do this or do I need to create a regular form?

Django admin site is not appropriate for my use case.

Something like (which doesn't work of course...):

View

```
def edit_user(request,pk):
if request.method == 'POST':
    user_form = UserEditForm(queryset=User.objects.get(pk=pk),
                             data=request.POST)
    if user_form.is_valid():
        user_form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'User updated successfully')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Error updating your profile')
else:
    user_form = UserEditForm(queryset=User.objects.get(pk=pk))
return render(request, 'edit_user.html', {'user_form': user_form })
```

UserEdit Form

```
class UserEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
```

Template:

```
% block content %}
<h1>Edit User:</h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ user_form.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Save changes" class="btn btn-primary"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="{% url 'manage_users' %}" class="btn btn-secondary">Manage</a></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Example URL: profile/edit-user/3/

I want the form populated with the PK of the user (the 3 in this case) NOT like my edit your own profile which passes in instance=request.user:

View for profile

```
def user_profile(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user,
                             data=request.POST)
    profile_form = UserProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile,
                                   data=request.POST,
                                   files=request.FILES)
    if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        user_form.save()
        profile_form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Profile updated successfully')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Error updating your profile')
else:
    user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
    profile_form = UserProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile)
return render(request, 'profile_edit.html', {'user_form': user_form,
                                             'profile_form': profile_form})
```

Still very new to django...

Thanks for your help.

BCBB

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. What do you mean, "manage" users? What is the queryset argument to the form supposed to do? Why are you passing an instance as that argument instead of a queryset?

Comment: Some users are app support and can update information such as email address for a user.

Comment: That didn't seem to answer any of my questions. Perhaps you should post the code for UserEditForm. And the error you get when you try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get the user you want and then pass it in to the form as the instance argument, exactly as you did with the logged in user.

```
def edit_user(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=user,
                                 data=request.POST)
         ...
    else:
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=user)
    ...
```

Comment: arrrg... I knew it would be something simple... Thanks for your help!